# Should Each Application Have Their Own User For Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

We have a number of apps, all are accessing the DB with the same user. There a number of tables, each app deals with a different table.

Should each app have it's own user?

Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking -- YES.

Your applications have a potential to access / corrupt each others' data otherwise. Individual users would allow setting up permissions so that each app only sees / has access to the data it requires.

This is called a "principle of least privilege".